# Read a file and compare the contents of the file to pipeline parameters using Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a file file.txt that gets created with some content, sample as below

```
 /abc/jenkins/data/jobs/random/workspace/file.txt - With below content 
  ------------------------- 
 [abc, hde, jef ,dgd , 1243, 324# ,23534 ....]
  ==> First step
  id - 1235
  branch - 104
  path - dthdp:/opt/usr/nimb/src/emc/crm/104/mat/1235
  area - crm
  rev - 10
  status - Running
```

I have set of parameters that i get as input from my pipeline

```
  **Sample parameters**
  buildnum - 1235
  prod - crm
  trunk - 104 ... etc
```

I am trying to read the file and compare its data to the parameters and Print "All the parameters match" if

```
 [ buildnum parameter = id  value in file , prod parameter= area value in file , branch parameter = trunk value in file ]
```

Can anyone help how to write it in groovy , below doesn't work

```
    def file = new File(env.WORKSPACE+"/file.txt")
            def lineCount = 0
          file.eachLine { line ->
    def parts = line.split '\n'
              println "parts"
    if ( parts != 'params.buildnum' )
       System.err.println "Failure! Doesnt match with buildnm..."
    if ( parts !=  'params.trunk' )
      System.err.println "Failure! Doesnt match with trunk..."
     lineCount++
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//just test data from file
def data = ''' 
[abc, hde, jef ,dgd , 1243, 324# ,23534 ....]
  ==> First step
  id - 1235
  branch - 104
  path - dthdp:/opt/usr/nimb/src/emc/crm/104/mat/1235
  area - crm
  rev - 10
  status - Running
  '''
def m = /\s*(\w+)\s*-\s*(.*)/

def reader = new StringReader(data)
//to get reader from file use the following code:
//def reader = new File(FILE_PATH).newReader()

//read lines and keep only valid according to regexp
def lines = reader.readLines().findAll{it=~m}
//convert valid lines into a map
def fmap = lines.collectEntries{ (it=~m).find{true}.with{[it[1],it[2]]} }
//validate value in map against parameter
assert fmap.id == '1235'
```

Comment: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.io.StringReader(java.io.File)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1732)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1532)

Comment: @DevOops, use: `new File(FILE_PATH).newReader()`

Comment: def fileToRead = new file("/ads/jenkins/data/jobs/form/workspace/filelog.txt").newReader()                                             I still get the same error

Comment: check the modified answer. for you - just comment one line with `def reader = ...` and uncomment another.